# Can a (named) function introspect the name it was invoked with?

Tags: r, introspection

Suppose that a function has been bound to multiple names (each in a different binding environment).  Is there a way for it to find out which of these names (if any) was used to invoke it?

A trivial example:

```
original.name <- function () cat("don't know my name (yet)...\n")
call.thunk <- function (thunk) thunk()
foo <- original.name

foo()
## don't know my name (yet)...
call.thunk(original.name)
## don't know my name (yet)...
```

In the first call above the function is called with the name `foo`; in the second one, it is called with the name `thunk`.  Could the function's body be modified so that it can ascertain this information?

---

(This question is motivated by wanting to learn more about introspection in R; I'm not trying to solve any specific problem.)

Comment: Adding some example code which sets up an environment you describe will make it easier for people to understand what you want, and provide a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `sys.call`:

```
g <- f <- function() sys.call()[[1]]
f()
## f
```

Note that:

- this returns an object of class `"name"`.  To get the name as a character string use `as.character(sys.call()[[1]])` .
- `match.call()[[1]]` would also work as the body